# Problemas con el mysqli_num_rows() al momento de utilizarlo

Tags: php

he estado utilizando `mysqli_num_rows()` y me ha funcionado para detectar si existe algún usuario existe e etc, pero tengo problemas con ello al momento de utilizarlo, si una tabla está vacía me envía false y no me deja enviar el formulario como tal, es decir, me da `else{ echo 'ejemplo: error'; }` todo el tiempo, y me preguntaba cómo solucionar ese error básico.

Ejemplo del error.

```
// Selecciona todo dependiendo del user_id, pero a no ver baneos por esa id de usuario prácticamente se encuentra vacía la tabla bans.
$selectban = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE user_id = '".$userToBan."'");  

if(mysqli_num_rows($selectban)){ // Si envía 0 saltará el error, pero lo mostrará siempre porque la tabla 'bans' está vacía.
  while($user_data = $select->fetch_assoc()){
    $id = $user_data['id'];
    $ip = $user_data['ip_register'];
    $db->real_query("INSERT INTO bans (user_id,ip,machine_id,user_staff_id,timestamp,ban_expire,ban_reason,type,cfh_topic) 
            VALUES ('" . $id . "', '".$ip."', '', '". HK_Id ."', '', '".$banTime."', '".$reason."', '".$banType."', '')");
    header("Refresh: 5, URL=?_page=banuser");
    echo '<div class="alert green">'. $_POST["valueToBan"] . ' ha sido baneado por ' . $time_date . '</div>';
  }
}
else{ // Error, este debería salir si se encuentra un baneo activo, es decir, si el usuario introducido se encuentra en la tabla 'bans' por el user_id del mismo.
echo '<div class="alert red">El usuario ya tiene un baneo activo, intente más tarde...</div>';
}
```

Comment: ¿por qué no agregar esto? `if(mysqli_num_rows($selectban) > 0)` es decir evaluar su contenido en forma numérica para que si no hay registros retorne 0 y entonces puedas hacer el alta o en caso de tener por lo menos un registro mandar el mensaje del else

Comment: No es bueno que mezcles tus estilos, veo que usas `orientado a objetos` y luego `procedimientos`. Usa tu `num_row` de la siguiente forma `if ($selectban->num_rows > 0)` ya que tu query es al estilo `orientado a objetos`.

Answer (score 0):

No es bueno que mezcles tus estilos, veo que usas en tu sentencia orientado a objetos y luego en tu `num_rows` procedimientos. Deberia quedar algo asi `if ($selectban->num_rows > 0)`.

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
//Sentencia.
$selectban = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE user_id = '".$userToBan."' LIMIT 1");  

//Comprobamos si existe registro en la BD.
if($selectban->num_rows == 1){
    //Obtenemos resultado DB.
    while($user_data = $select->fetch_assoc()){
        //Datos BD.
        $id = $user_data['id'];
        $ip = $user_data['ip_register'];
        //Insertar datos
        $db->real_query("INSERT INTO bans (user_id,ip,machine_id,user_staff_id,timestamp,ban_expire,ban_reason,type,cfh_topic) 
                VALUES ('" . $id . "', '".$ip."', '', '". HK_Id ."', '', '".$banTime."', '".$reason."', '".$banType."', '')");
        //Refrescar url  
        header("Refresh: 5, URL=?_page=banuser");
        //Mensaje.
        echo '<div class="alert green">'. $_POST["valueToBan"] . ' ha sido baneado por ' . $time_date . '</div>';
    }
} else{ // Baneo activo.
    echo '<div class="alert red">El usuario ya tiene un baneo activo, intente más tarde...</div>';
}
```